# Php, Mysql insert data to database twice

Tags: php, mysql, google-chrome, firefox

```
<?php
// configuration

$dbhost     = "xxxxx";
$dbname     = "xxxxx";
$dbuser     = "xxxxx";
$dbpass     = "xxxxx";

// database connection
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost;dbname=$dbname",$dbuser,$dbpass);

// new data

$author = 'test';

// query
$sql = "INSERT INTO video (url) VALUES (:t)";
$q = $conn->prepare($sql);
if($q->execute(array(':t'=>$author)))
{
    echo "ok";
}else
{
    echo "notok";
}


?>
```

This is a simple php mysql script for inserting data into database. But the strange problem is it works well in android default browser, but when i access it from google chrome or firefox from my pc it insert the value "test" two times into the database, but when i am using this from android default browser it works well, no double post. Very strange to me. My question is why this type of strange behavior? I am using web server, no localhost.

Comment: Nothing in this php code would cause it to naturally insert twice. The key point is where is the event that dispatches this script?

Comment: No in my site when i insert data to my database this error occur. I cant post that script. So i have uploaded this script for testing purpose and run it directly, same problem occur.

Comment: Your browser seems to just be loading the page twice. PHP is on your server, not the browser. So as @Ohgodwhy said, it's nothing in your PHP code that is causing this.

Comment: How it possible, i just copy paste the url to address bar and press enter button, no double post i think. :(

Comment: You get this problem with both Google Chrome and Firefox?

Comment: Yes this problem occur from two browser.